# curl POST ( CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS )

Tags: php, post, curl

I am trying to log into a forum and send a message to an user but no effect.

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://exemple.com/login.php'); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'username=USER&password=1234567'); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt'); 
$login = curl_exec ($ch); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://exemple.com/privatemessage.php?receiver=7067'); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'msg=Test'); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$post = curl_exec ($ch); 

curl_close ($ch); 

print_r($login) . "\n"; 
?>
```

What is wrong ? It's first time using cURL ..

Thanks for your time...

Here is the HTML part

```
            <br/></br><br/></br>
            <div class="rowElem">
                <label>Username</label> 
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="input" value="" size="20" tabindex="10" />

            </div>
            <div class="rowElem">
                <label>Password</label> 
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="input" value="" size="20" tabindex="20" />
            </div>
            <div class="rowElem">
                <label></label> 
                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="button-primary"/>
            </div>
```

Comment: What happens when you run it? Do you get an error message? How do you know that it's not working?

Comment: Could be a lot of things.  I'm guessing that you are not logging in correctly.  Perhaps the site is checking referer, or for other form fields to be set that you are not passing (like the submit button value eg)

Comment: Is COOKIEJAR writable by apache (or whoever is running this)?  I could be wrong about this too, but I think you need to specify the cookie file in the second request.

Comment: You should check for a form id or some other CSRF token.  You'll most likely have to hit the login page once to get it, and then you can use it in a follow up POST request to login.

Comment: @Adam, I looked at online users from another account :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$login = curl_exec ($ch); 
if ($login === FALSE) {
    die(curl_error($ch));
}
```

and similar for the second curl run. You should never assume that a call to an external service succeeded. die() is useful to kill things in development. For product you can replace it with a more comprehensive error handler.